# Add brand logo on each WooCommerce product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to add the brand logo on WooCommerce product?

I have created multiple products which of different brand and I would like to add the brand logo on each product images and yes products are having different categories definitely I would like to add particular brand logo which belongs to that category. And only admin will  allow do this.

For now, I need to do lots of photoshop work for adding product images with the brand so I would like to skip my photoshop work and adding functionality for admin to add or place the brand logo on the product image.

If someone is having a solution please let me know and if is there any plugin is available that one is also ok.

Now I am adding blank product images like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsCmx.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/059VD.jpg) is what I am doing with Photoshop.

So, is there any way for reducing this work and provide functionality to admin for doing this at the backend.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the image source with the URL of your own image

```
function sv_add_logo_above_wc_shop_image() {

    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/skyverge-logo.png" class="aligncenter" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'sv_add_logo_above_wc_shop_image', 9 );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @zaheer . but where I need to replace above code and from where I'm adding the brand logo.